# Cast from GrammaticalStructure to Tree

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying out the new NN Dependency Parser from Stanford. According to the demo they have provided, this is how the parsing is done:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.DocumentPreprocessor;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructure;
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser;

...

GrammaticalStructure gs = null;

DocumentPreprocessor tokenizer = new DocumentPreprocessor(new StringReader(sentence));
for (List<HasWord> sent : tokenizer) {
    List<TaggedWord> tagged = tagger.tagSentence(sent);
    gs = parser.predict(tagged);

    // Print typed dependencies
    System.out.println(Grammatical structure: " + gs);
}
```

Now, what I want to do is this object `gs`, which is of class `GrammaticalStructure`, to be casted as a `Tree` object from `edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree`.

I naively tried out with simple casting:

```
Tree t = (Tree) gs;
```

but, this is not possible (the IDE gives an error: Cannot cast from `GrammaticalStructure` to `Tree`).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the Tree using `gs.root()`.
According to the [documentation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/GrammaticalStructure.html#root--), that method returns a Tree (actually, a `TreeGraphNode`) which represents the grammatical structure.

You could print that tree in a human-friendly way with `gs.root().pennPrint()`.

Comment: First of all, tnx a lot for your answer! However, I've already tried that, but it returns an empty tree (it only has ROOT-0). When I try with `gs.root().pennPrint()` it prints just `ROOT`, although the grammatical structure object `gs` is not empty. Any other suggestion?